# Java Internationalisation - ISO ISO 3166-2 (subdivisions - e.g. provinces or states) or UN/LOCODE - library

Tags: java, scala, internationalization, open-source, iso

I'm looking for a JVM library in Java, Scala etc which supports mapping between various country subdivisions/states as defined in the [ISO 3166-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2) standard.

Is there a recommended Java Library (preferable on maven) or an API like Google Maps which can do this mapping.

For example in Australia we have the following;

```
Code    Subdivision name (en)   Subdivision category
AU-NSW   New South Wales                state
AU-QLD   Queensland                     state
AU-SA    South Australia                state
AU-TAS   Tasmania                       state
AU-VIC   Victoria                       state
AU-WA    Western Australia              state
AU-ACT   Australian Capital Territory   territory
AU-NT    Northern Territory             territory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take a look at this one: [scala-iso](https://github.com/vitorsvieira/scala-iso). This is the best option I've found so far.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/tobias-/i18n-subdivisions).It is the only library i could find.
Alternatively you could use the csv file by official body.

Comment: Question seeking recommendations for libraries, books and other resources are off-topic for Stack Overflow and shouldn't really be answered.